# R Question: adding colors to geom_point() for two different factors and a legend to match, but one that doesn't include other factors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make the data points pink and blue for gender and have a corresponding legend. Whenever I do this it creates a legend that also has all of the geom_line() colors in it. How can I do this?

```
ggplot(Signs, aes(x = HrsAfterFirstScan, y = ContusionVol)) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = HrsAfterFirstScan, y = ContusionVol, color = ParticipantID), show.legend = FALSE) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = HrsAfter, y = IPH, shape = Sign)) + 
  ylab("Subdural Hemorrhage Volume") + 
  theme_bw() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 150))
```

[image]

Comment: It's a little "off-label" use to have color map to two different variables with different values/scales. You might look at the `ggnewscale` package to do this.

Comment: can you share part of your data so that we can run your code? try with `dput(Signs)`

Answer (score 1):

As long as you choose `shape = 21` for your `geom_point`s, you can choose a fill color that can be assigned to gender and therefore have its own legend.

We don't have your data, so here is a demonstration with some similarly formatted data in a reproducible format:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(time, values)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = group, group = paste(group, gender))) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = gender), shape = 21, size = 5)
```

[image]

You can choose your own colors for the points with `scale_fill_manual`, and the color of the lines separately with `scale_color_manual`

---

**Data used**

```r
set.seed(1) # Makes example reproducible

df <- data.frame(time = rep(1:5, 6),
                 values = c(replicate(6, cumsum(runif(5)), TRUE)),
                 group = rep(letters[1:3], each = 10),
                 gender = rep(rep(c("M", "F"), each = 5), 3))
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: This didn't work for my dataset

Comment: @RachelMona sorry to hear that. I could show a working solution if you included a sample of your data. If you can't adapt this approach and need specific working code, we need specifics of the problem including a sample of your data.